# scipy curve_fit give the initial guess values as optimal results when I set the bounds parameter

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a curve with a Gaussian plus a Lorentzian function, using the curve_fit function from scipy.

```
def gaussian(x, a, x0, sig):
    return a * np.exp(-1/2 * (x - x0)**2 / sig**2)

def lorentzian(x, a, b, c):
    return a*c**2/((x-b)**2+c**2)

def decompose(x, z, n, b, *par):
    hb_n = gaussian(x, par[0], 4861.3*(1+z), n)
    hb_b = lorentzian(x, par[1], 4861.3*(1+z), b)
    return hb_b + hb_n
```

And when I set the p0 parameter, I can get a reasonable result, which fits the curve well.

```
guess = [0.0001, 2, 10, 3e-16, 3e-16]
p, c = curve_fit(decompose, wave, residual, guess)
```

[fitting parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gh1y.png)
[the fitting model and data figure when I set the p0 parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4ZZc.png)

But if I set the p0 and bounds parameters simultaneously, the curve_fit function gives the initial guess as the final fitting result, which is rather deviated from the data.

```
guess = [0.0001, 2, 10, 3e-16, 3e-16]
p, c = curve_fit(decompose, wave, residual, guess, bounds=([-0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0.001, 10, 100, 1e-15, 1e-15]))
```

[fitting parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go5JK.png)
[the fitting model and data figure when I set the p0 and bounds parameters simultaneously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnK8A.png)

I have tried many different combinations of boundaries for the parameters, but the fitting results invariably return the initial guess values. I've been stuck in this problem for a long time. I would be very grateful if anyone can give me some advice to solve this problem.

Comment: Add the option `full_output=True` to the call of [`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), update your code to accept the additional return values, and check the values of `ier` and `mesg`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to a combination of the optimization algorithm and its parameters.

From the [official documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

> method{‘lm’, ‘trf’, ‘dogbox’}, optional
>
> Method to use for optimization. See least_squares for more details.
> Default is ‘**lm’ for unconstrained problems and ‘trf’ if bounds** are
> provided. The method ‘lm’ won’t work when the number of observations
> is less than the number of variables, use ‘trf’ or ‘dogbox’ in this
> case.

So when you add bound constraints `curve_fit` will use different optimization algorithm (trust region instead of Levenberg-Marquardt).

To debug the problem you can try to set `full_output=True` as [Warren Weckesser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217358/warren-weckesser) noted in the comments.

In the case of the fit with bounds you will see something similar to:

```
'nfev': 1
`gtol` termination condition is satisfied.
```

So the optimization stopped after the first iteration. That's why founed parameters similar to the initial guess.

To fix this you can specify lower `gtol` parameter. Full list of available parameters you can find here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares

Example:
[image]

Code:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def gaussian(x, a, x0, sig):
    return a * np.exp(-1 / 2 * (x - x0) ** 2 / sig**2)


def lorentzian(x, a, b, c):
    return a * c**2 / ((x - b) ** 2 + c**2)


def decompose(x, z, n, b, *par):
    hb_n = gaussian(x, par[0], 4861.3 * (1 + z), n)
    hb_b = lorentzian(x, par[1], 4861.3 * (1 + z), b)
    return hb_b + hb_n


gt_parameters = [-2.42688295e-4, 2.3477827, 1.56977708e1, 4.47455820e-16, 2.2193466e-16]
wave = np.linspace(4750, 5000, num=400)

gt_curve = decompose(wave, *gt_parameters)
noisy_curve = gt_curve + np.random.normal(0, 2e-17, size=len(wave))

guess = [0.0001, 2, 10, 3e-16, 3e-16]
bounds = ([-0.001, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0.001, 10, 100, 1e-15, 1e-15])
options = [
    ("Levenberg-Marquardt without bounds", dict(method="lm")),
    ("Trust Region without bounds", dict(method="trf")),
    ("Trust Region with bounds", dict(method="trf", bounds=bounds)),
    (
        "Trust Region with bounds + fixed tolerance",
        dict(method="trf", bounds=bounds, gtol=1e-36),
    ),
]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(options))
for (title, fit_params), ax in zip(options, axs):
    ax.set_title(title)

    p, c = curve_fit(decompose, wave, noisy_curve, guess, **fit_params)

    fitted_curve = decompose(wave, *p)

    ax.plot(wave, gt_curve, label="gt_curve")
    ax.plot(wave, noisy_curve, label="noisy")
    ax.plot(wave, fitted_curve, label="fitted_curve")


handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
fig.legend(handles, labels)
plt.show()
```